# puppeteer-recorder: Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed

Tags: node.js

i use puppeteer-recorder,code is:

```
await record({
    browser:    browser, 
    page: page, 
    output: '8output.webm',
    fps: 8,
    frames: 8 * 10, 
    prepare: function (browser, page) {}, 
    render: function (browser, page, frame) {} 
});
```

but run with error:

```
Error [ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED]: Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed
at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:413:19)
at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:401:5)
at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:301:11)
at /data/pupp_test/node_modules/puppeteer-recorder/index.js:72:12
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at write (/data/pupp_test/node_modules/puppeteer-recorder/index.js:71:3)
at module.exports.record (/data/pupp_test/node_modules/puppeteer-recorder/index.js:44:11)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:5)
at async /data/pupp_test/test2.js:22:5
```

my ffmpeg is configure with "--enable-libvpx --enable-libvorbis"

```
  ffmpeg version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)
  configuration: --enable-libvpx --enable-libvorbis
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
```

how to resolve the error(Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

to reinstall libvpx。see in https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos

```
git clone --depth 1 https://chromium.googlesource.com/webm/libvpx.git
cd libvpx
./configure --disable-examples --disable-unit-tests --enable-vp9-highbitdepth --as=yasm
make
make install
```